# Map view adding only one Annotation

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I dont know i have mutable array ok mkannotation it is adding only one that too last one here is my code

[code http://web.missouri.edu/~dnk6y2/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2011.46.05%20PM.png](http://web.missouri.edu/~dnk6y2/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2011.46.05%20PM.png)

Comment: I figured it out thanks.

My code was adding a one annotation to my array and that was the problem.Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `kAnnotations` (bad name by the way. That style of name `kName` is usually used for constants) to the `contacts` array, then changing its values and adding it again. But it is still the same object. Every time you change `kAnnotations`'s coordinate and tile you're changing the one in the `contacts` array too. You need to create a new kAnnotation each time like this

```
CustomAnnotation *customAnno = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init;
customAnno.coorindate = coord;
customAnno.title = name;
[contacts addObject:customAnno];
```